# Can't figure out why a for loop won't run

Tags: java, for-loop, palindrome

I've tried embedding println checks within and above/below the for loop in this, but I can't find a problem with the loop itself.

Function is part of a simple palindrome checker.

```
public static String checkPalindrome(String x) {
    x=x.toLowerCase();
    String trimmedX = x.replaceAll("\\W","");
    String reverseX = new StringBuilder(trimmedX).reverse().toString();
    int length= trimmedX.length();
    for (int i=0;i>length;i++){
        if (trimmedX.charAt(i)!=reverseX.charAt(i)) {
            String z = "It is not a palindrome.";
            return z;
        }
        String z = "It is a palindrome.";
    }
    return z;
}
```

I originally had Z set as "it is" above the for loop, but in trying to fix things I've moved it inside the for loop, which confirmed the loop not running.

Comment: length = 0. Check to make sure the values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: This code doesn't actually compile.  So what you're running must be something slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should inspect the loop more closely:

```
for (int i=0;i>length;i++){
```

I think there is an issue with the check on `i`.

Comment: Not saying this is the only problem but the loop check is definitely wrong - it will never run the body of the loop unless the length is negative, in which case it will run for a LONG time. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace > with <

```
for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
```